Sidebar HTML form not submitting data to Google Sheet
I'm trying to build a sidebar HTML form which adds the data entered into the form as a new row of the sheet when the "Submit" button is pressed. I've successfully managed to create the sidebar and the HTML form, but I can't seem to figure out how to make the data entered into the form submit and add a row. I'm pretty novice at coding, and I can't figure out why this is not working - I've followed several tutorials exactly as shown and none of them seem to work.
Here is the javascript part:
//@OnlyCurrentDoc

function onOpen() {
 SpreadsheetApp
   .getUi()
   .createMenu("Intake Form")
   .addItem("Show Intake Form", "showAdminSidebar")
   .addToUi();
}

function showAdminSidebar() {
 var widget = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile("Intake Form.html");
 widget.setTitle("Intake Form");
 SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showSidebar(widget);
}

function appendRowFromFormSubmit(form) {
 var row = [form.jobID, form.customerName, form.customerAddress, form.customerPostcode, form.customerPhone, form.customerEmail, form.applianceMake, form.applianceModel, form.reportedFault, form.servicesRequired, form.serviceLocation, form.inspectionFee, form.call-outFee];
 SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet(Worksheet).appendRow(row);
}

Here is the code for the HTML form:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
   <base target="_top">
   <script>
     function submitForm() {
       google.script.run.appendRowFromFormSubmit(document.getElementById("intakeForm"));
     }

</script>
 </head>
 <body>
   <h2>Enter Customer Details</h2>
   <form id="intakeForm">
     <label for="jobID">Job ID</label>
     <input type="text" id="jobID" name="jobID"><br><br>
     <label for="customerName">Customer Name</label>
     <input type="text" id="customerName" name="customerName"><br><br>
     <label for="customerAddress">Customer Address</label>
     <input type="text" id="customerAddress" name="customerAddress"><br><br>
     <label for="customerPostcode">Customer Postcode</label>
     <input type="text" id="customerPostcode" name="customerPostcode"><br><br>
     <label for="customerPhone">Customer Phone</label>
     <input type="text" id="customerPhone" name="customerPhone"><br><br>
     <label for="customerEmail">Customer email</label>
     <input type="text" id="customerEmail" name="customerEmail"><br><br>
     <label for="applianceMake">Appliance Make</label>
     <input type="text" id="applianceMake" name="applianceMake"><br><br>
     <label for="applianceModel">Appliance Model</label>
     <input type="text" id="applianceModel" name="applianceModel"><br><br>
     <label for="reportedFault">Reported Fault</label>
     <input type="text" id="reportedFault" name="reportedFault"><br><br>
     <div>
       <label for="servicesRequested">Services Requested:</label><br>
       <input type="checkbox" id="inspection" name="servicesRequested" value="Inspection" multiple>
       <label for="inspection">Inspection</label><br>
       <input type="checkbox" id="servicing" name="servicesRequested" value="Servicing">
       <label for="servicing">Servicing</label><br>
       <input type="checkbox" id="repairs" name="servicesRequested" value="Repairs">
       <label for="repairs">Repairs</label><br>
       <input type="checkbox" id="refurbishedAppliance" name="servicesRequested" value="Refurbished Appliance">
       <label for="refurbishedAppliance">Refurbished Appliance</label><br><br>
       <div>
       <label for="serviceLocation">Services Requested:</label><br> 
       <input type="checkbox" id="atWorkshop" name="serviceLocation" value="At Workshop">
       <label for="atWorkshop">At Workshop</label><br>
       <input type="checkbox" id="onsite" name="serviceLocation" value="Onsite">
       <label for="onsite">Onsite</label><br>
       <div>
     <label for="inspectionFee">Inspection Fee</label>
     <input type="text" id="inspectionFee" name="inspectionFee"><br><br>
     <label for="calloutFee">Call-out Fee</label>
     <input type="text" id="calloutFee" name="calloutFee"><br><br>
    <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="submitForm();">
   </form>
 </body>
</html>

Any ideas on how to get the form data to add as a new row when I press "Submit"?

You should probably apply preventDefault(). See Code.gs and index.html at Forms.

The following works on my end;
Code.gs module;
function onOpen() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
    .createMenu('Intake Form')
    .addItem("Show Intake Form", "showAdminSidebar")
    .addToUi();
}

// Sidebar
function showAdminSidebar() {
  var widget = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile("Intake Form.html");
  widget.setTitle("Intake Form");
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showSidebar(widget);
}

// Inserting data from the form
function addData(array) {
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().appendRow(array);
}

.
Intake Form.html module;
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <style>
      body {
        background: #A5B6B5;
        background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(203, 255, 84, 0.5) .05em, transparent .1em), linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(203, 255, 84, 0.5) .02em, transparent .1em);
        background-size: 1em 1em;
      }
    </style>
    <script>
      function submitForm() {
        // Select all 'input' elements with type= 'text' or type= 'checkbox' where checkbox type input elements are 'checked'
        const inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="text"],input[type="checkbox"]:checked');
        let array = [];

        for (const input of inputs) {
          array.push(input.value);
        }

        if (array.join('') == '') {
          alert('The form is empty!');
          return;
        }

        // Send data to the sheet
        google.script.run.addData(array);

        // Clear form
        inputs.forEach(input => input.value = '');
      }
     </script>
 </head>
 
 <body>
   <h2>Enter Customer Details</h2>
   <form id="intakeForm">
     <label for="jobID">Job ID</label>
     <input type="text" id="jobID" name="jobID"><br><br>
     <label for="customerName">Customer Name</label>
     <input type="text" id="customerName" name="customerName"><br><br>
     <label for="customerAddress">Customer Address</label>
     <input type="text" id="customerAddress" name="customerAddress"><br><br>
     <label for="customerPostcode">Customer Postcode</label>
     <input type="text" id="customerPostcode" name="customerPostcode"><br><br>
     <label for="customerPhone">Customer Phone</label>
     <input type="text" id="customerPhone" name="customerPhone"><br><br>
     <label for="customerEmail">Customer email</label>
     <input type="text" id="customerEmail" name="customerEmail"><br><br>
     <label for="applianceMake">Appliance Make</label>
     <input type="text" id="applianceMake" name="applianceMake"><br><br>
     <label for="applianceModel">Appliance Model</label>
     <input type="text" id="applianceModel" name="applianceModel"><br><br>
     <label for="reportedFault">Reported Fault</label>
     <input type="text" id="reportedFault" name="reportedFault"><br><br>
     <div>
        <label for="servicesRequested">Services Requested:</label><br>
        <input type="checkbox" id="inspection" name="servicesRequested" value="Inspection" multiple>
        <label for="inspection">Inspection</label><br>
        <input type="checkbox" id="servicing" name="servicesRequested" value="Servicing">
        <label for="servicing">Servicing</label><br>
        <input type="checkbox" id="repairs" name="servicesRequested" value="Repairs">
        <label for="repairs">Repairs</label><br>
        <input type="checkbox" id="refurbishedAppliance" name="servicesRequested" value="Refurbished Appliance">
        <label for="refurbishedAppliance">Refurbished Appliance</label><br><br>
      </div>
      <div>
        <label for="serviceLocation">Services Requested:</label><br> 
        <input type="checkbox" id="atWorkshop" name="serviceLocation" value="At Workshop">
        <label for="atWorkshop">At Workshop</label><br>
        <input type="checkbox" id="onsite" name="serviceLocation" value="Onsite">
        <label for="onsite">Onsite</label><br>
      </div>
     <label for="inspectionFee">Inspection Fee</label>
     <input type="text" id="inspectionFee" name="inspectionFee"><br><br>
     <label for="calloutFee">Call-out Fee</label>
     <input type="text" id="calloutFee" name="calloutFee"><br><br>
    <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="submitForm();">
   </form>
 </body>
</html>

